# Python script skyrockets size of pagefile.sys

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory

I wrote a Python script that tends to crash sometimes with a Memory Allocation Error. I noticed that the pagefile.sys of my Win10 64 system skyrockets in this script and exceeds the free memory.
My current solution is to run the script in steps, so that every time the script runs through, the pagefile empties.
I would like the script to run through all at once, though.
Moving the pagefile to another drive is not an option, unfortunately, because I only have this one drive and moving the pagefile to an external drive does not seem to work.

During my research, I found out about the module gc but that is not working:

```
import gc
```

and after every iteration I use

```
gc.collect()
```

Am I using it wrong or is there another (python-based!) option?

[Edit:]
The script is very basic and only iterates over image files (using Pillow). The script only checks for width, height and resolution of the image, calculates the dimensions in cm.
If height > width, the image is rotated 90° counterclockwise.
The images are meant to be enlarged or shrunk to A3 size (42 x 29.7cm), so I use the width/height ratio to calculate whether I can enlarge the width to 42cm and the height remains < 29.7cm and in case the height is > 29.7cm, I enlarge the height to 29.7 cm.

For the moment, I do the actual enlargement/shrinking still in Photoshop. Based on whether it is a width/height enlargement, the file is moved to a certain folder that contains either one of those file types.

Anyways, the memory explosion happens in the iteration that only reads the file dimensions.
For that I use

```
with Image.open(imgOri) as pic:
    widthPX = pic.size[0]
    heightPX = pic.size[1]
    resolution = pic.info["dpi"][0]
    widthCM = float(widthPX) / resolution * 2.54
    heightCM = float(heightPX) / resolution * 2.54
```

I also calculate whether the shrinking would be too strong, the image gets divided in half and re-evaluated.

Even though it is unnecessary, I still added `pic.close`
to the `with open()`statement, because I thought Python may be keeping the image files open, but that didn't help.

Once the iteration finished, the pagefile.sys goes back to its original size, so in case that error occurs, I take some files out and do them gradually.

Comment: Hi Kai.  we're going to need a bit more detail on the ask.  can you provide an excerpt of the script you are trying to run so we know why you are using gc?  Even better, if you could condition the excerpt to have enough script we can execute?  Thanks

Comment: There's no generic "Use less memory" button to press. The solution to your memory issues is likely to be specific to what your script is doing. It may be that there will be some alternative algorithm or data structure that will help you a lot, but we can't guess at that without knowing *anything* about what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: @arcee123 I added the explanation of the script to the main post

Comment: I am not familiar with the gc module, I just found a code snippet in a sample code and experimented with it and ran it every once in a while, but that clearly didn't work :)